# Strange bug with maxCoeff in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I have:

```
VectorXd my_vector;
MatrixXd my_matrix;
```

and dimensions are compatible in expressions bellow.

I remember reading in the Eigen doc that it is always better to evaluate expressions as a whole rather than evaluating smaller chuncks and then recombining results, because it gives Eigen more opportunities to optimize.

With that in mind, I would use:

```
// (1)
int index;
(my_vector.transpose() * my_matrix.leftCols(n_cols+1)).maxCoeff(&index);
```

rather than:

```
// (2)
int index;
RowVectorXd temp = my_vector.transpose() * my_matrix.leftCols(n_cols+1);
temp.maxCoeff(&index);
```

However (1) crashes when `n_cols` = 1 while using (2) instead of (1) exactly at the same place seems to always work. (Note that `my_matrix` has more than 1 columns...)

QUESTIONS:
Why does (1) crash when (2) doesn't ???
How to prevent (1) from crashing while keeping it as a single expression?

The error comes from Eigen's internal machinery assertions and it seems to me that it is because in (1) `maxCoeff` doesn't seem to realize that it is called on a row vector and not a general matrix - please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can use `.eval()`. This effectively is the same as (2), just without the extra line of code:

```
(my_vector.transpose() * my_matrix.leftCols(n_cols + 1)).eval().maxCoeff(&index);
```

Regarding the internal workings of Eigen, when you call `maxCoeff` in case (1) the object that's being called on is (as you explicitly desired) a lazy evaluation construct (in this case `GeneralProduct<Transpose<..>,Block<...> >`) triggered by a call to `mat.coeff(0,0)` where `mat` is the `GeneralProduct`. Internally, the `mat` has `(n_cols + 1)` columns as opposed to 1 which is required by the row after the assertion (`Matrix<Scalar,1,1> result = *this;`)
This is what causes the evaluation, so we want to evaluate only the one element each time. Without the assert, trying to assign `*this` to `result` a resize is triggered causing the program to crash.

When using a temporary, the object is a `Matrix<double,1,-1,1,1,-1>` so `coeff(i,j)` just becomes a simple call to `m_storage.data()[colId + rowId * m_storage.cols()]`.

All this becomes a moot point in Eigen 3.3 as the entire `coeff(i,j)` is now `return m_evaluator.coeff(row, col);`

## TLDR

Upgrade to Eigen 3.3 (alpha) and the problem goes away.

Comment: Does this only save a line of code or it also allows Eigen to optimize the whole computation? I don't know if Eigen actually does it this way but I would imagine that a fully optimized computation would loop only once, whereas maybe `eval()` would force a first loop, and then `maxCoeff` would have to run a second loop?

Comment: That is correct. The `eval()` forces saving a temporary in memory, upon which the subsequent `maxCoeff` is run.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation. For the TLDR: I have to use my company's version, and they are not going to switch for an alpha version... For the more detailed explanation, I kind of lost it, especially I don't understand the reason behind asserting that there is only one column... Is that just a real 'bug' that is to be fixed in next versions?

Comment: I don't know if @ggael or others will address this in the 3.2 branch. The 3.3 branch looks like a rewrite, so once it's out of alpha/beta, you can consider it addressed. You can add an `#ifdef` that checks the Eigen version to use `.eval()` with the 3.2 version and not to with 3.3 or greater. Then when your company upgrades, it will kick in. I'd also add a regression test to make sure that it doesn't change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

To complete Avi's answer, let first add that to be evaluated efficiently, products have to evaluated into a temporary anyway, so calling `.eval()` is perfectly fine regardless of Eigen's version.

The current assertion that you are observing:

```
Assertion failed: (this->rows() == 1 && this->cols() == 1), function coeff, file ../eigen3.2/Eigen/src/Core/ProductBase.h, line 148
```

is to make sure that a product expression is not evaluated coefficient-wise by accident (except for a inner products). This explanation could be added in the assertion message to make it more clear.

Nevertheless, in you case you did not explicitly called the `coeff()` or `operator(i,j)` yourself, this is thus a bug in Eigen, and more precisely in `Eigen::Visitor` which should evaluate the nested product expression for you. This will be fixed in 3.2.8.

Finally, if you known that both `n_cols+1` and `my_vector` are very small you can avoid this temporary using a lazy product:

```
my_vector.transpose().lazyProduct(my_matrix.leftCols(n_cols+1)).maxCoeff(&index);
```

**edit:** for the record here is the [fix](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/commits/4d5b6143c133/).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! So just to make things perfectly clear: is my version (2) perfectly equivalent to Avi's `eval()` version? Or is it still better to let Eigen create and deal with its own 'hidden' temporary using `eval()`?